# converting from Form axis to Picturebox axis

Tags: c#, picturebox, converters

[image: pic]

I need to convert axis from the default axis(black) to picturebox axis(red) which sits on panel1(AutoSize).
The mission is to show the cursor position in world and window screen.
I tried many combination with `PictureBox.Location`/`Cursor.Position`/`Panel.Location` etc but couldn't get the red axis values.
Hope you can help me with that issue.

the code so far:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        corX = panel1.Location.X + Cursor.Position.X - 1000;
        corY = -panel1.Location.Y - pictureBox1.Size.Height + Cursor.Position.Y + 1000;
        mousePositionX.Text = "Window Position:{X=" +corX.ToString()+'}' + ' '+"{Y="+corY.ToString()+'}';
        screen.Text = "World Postion:" + Form1.MousePosition.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It is very unclear why the panel's Location property matters.  So start by just removing it.  The scaling is completely unclear as well.

Comment: scaling in unnecessary, Just need to move the 0,0 to -1000,-1000.
Thought that maybe panel.location.X is the gap from X(0,0) to X(-1000,y)

Comment: -1000,-1000 would be "off the screen" top left is 0,0 unless we aren't talking mouse coordinates at all.

Comment: -1000,1000 are new axis. Nothing to deal with panel.location.
@canahari is doesn't work. Missing some pixels.
[pic2](http://tinypic.com/r/24mf3ur/6)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

For y it is

```
    -y+pictureBox1.Bottom
```

where y is the mouse's y coordinate inside that black window. For x it is: -x+pictureBox1.Left

Comment: Oh well, it starts to be unclear to me as well. I don't know what those -1000s are but I thought they might be the position of your picturebox's bottomleft corner in "black box coordinates". But it obviously wouldn't be visibe if any of its coords would be -1000.

Comment: But then, if you want your point to be -1000,-1000 if it lies to the red origo then just add -1000 to my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

either
The top left in both windows is 0,0, and the bottom right width -1, height - 1

So scaling would be the answer

If you want the position in both windows to be the same screen coordinate, windows already does that for you...

Comment: another question, is there option to debug all the Location/Properties? but similar to Watch tab in debugging mode?

Comment: Eh? not sure I get you there. Do you mean you want top see whats going on while the app is running?

Comment: Yes. To know all the things above while mouse is moving.
Is it possible without making many labels?

Comment: You could log it to a file, you could delegate you logic to another class and then write a form to show you it's state i.e. a lot of labels but on an other form. Or have a logging window popped up by secret keypress. Just a little form with scrolling textbox and a method that takes a string and appends it ( clear button is useful as well). Then in your code you do if (logging) log(Someusefultext);